# Get font name from Google Fonts URL with regular expression

Tags: php

Please tell me how to `preg_match` font names from the Google Fonts URL.

For example, I want to extract the font name from:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab
```

in order to get the font names `Oswald` and `Roboto Slab`.

Comment: You can start here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: If you're stuck on regexs, you could just use `str_replace` for this - just remove `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=` and you're mostly there. But, do give the regex a go yourself - it's a good thing to learn!

Comment: Are you obtaining the URLs from HTML or some other source, because regular expressions may not be the best choice. The can be a little sluggish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what you might do with [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), however be careful data mining Google.

```
<?php
$urls = array("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300",
"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab");

$patterns = array(
      //replace the path root
'!^http://fonts.googleapis.com/css\?!',
      //capture the family and avoid and any following attributes in the URI.
'!(family=[^&:]+).*$!',
      //delete the variable name
'!family=!',
      //replace the plus sign
'!\+!');
$replacements = array(
"",
'$1',
'',
' ');

foreach($urls as $url){
    $font = preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$url);
    echo $font;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid regexp's

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$queryString =  $parsedUrl['query']; 
$parsedQueryString = parse_str($queryString);
$fontName = array_shift(explode(':', $parsedQueryString['family']));
$idealFontName = urldecode($fontName);
echo $idealFontName;
```

Comment: This doesn't replace the `+` with a space.